# Can we use select statement to fetch second set of results ignoring previous result set in the same session?

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I am executing an Oracle query to return 10 records from 100 records using a select statement.

Now I am required to execute the same query second time to fetch the next set of rows (i.e rows 11 - 20) in the same session and so on.

Is it possible to accomplish this without using additional column?

Comment: Please show us your current query.

Comment: Are you saying that every time you query it, you would like to fetch the next 10 rows ?

Comment: What are you using to execute and fetch those records? Is it pl/sql or remote client?

Comment: welll, if you execute the same exact query (with the same exact WHERE conditions) you will the the same exact rows.  There is a bigger picture here you are not showing.  What process is consuming the rows you select?  How do you propose to keep track of which rows you've already selected?  BTW, tables have rows, not records.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from version 12 Oracle allows to do this by the means of fetch and offset commands

```
create table some_table(some_col number);

insert into some_table values(1);
insert into some_table values(2);
insert into some_table values(3);
insert into some_table values(4);

select *
  from some_table
  order by 1
  fetch first 2 rows only;

/* returns: 
   1
   2 */

select *
  from some_table
  order by 1
  offset 2 rows
  fetch first 2 rows only;

/* returns:
   3
   4 */
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this? ([pagination](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-do-pagination-in-oracle-database-sql-query))

```
   SELECT * FROM (
    
        SELECT
    
          ord.*,
    
          row_number() over (ORDER BY ord.order_id ASC) line_number
    
        FROM Orders ord
    
      ) WHERE line_number BETWEEN 11 AND 20  ORDER BY line_number;
```